# Exception on sending big files through java sockets

Tags: java, arrays, image, file, sockets

I'm creating a Chat in java for a university project, and one of the requirements is each user must have an image associate, this can be done through registration windows and data modification windows, in registration everything works great, but on the modification window, the program throws an exception when i try to send big files, both codes (registration and modification) are basiccally the same, changing only variables and path, but still gives my problem only in modification

Here is my code:

Client:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new    File(usuario.getImagen().getCanonicalPath()));
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] size = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(byteArrayOutputStream.size()).array();
salida.write(size);
salida.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
salida.flush();
```

Server:

```
dir = new File ("." + "/Documentos/Imagenes de Verificacion/" +
                    usuarioRegistro.getNombreDeUsuario() + ".jpg");
sizeAr = new byte[4];
entrada.read(sizeAr);
size = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeAr).asIntBuffer().get();
imageAr = new byte[size];
entrada.readFully(imageAr);
image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageAr));
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(dir.getCanonicalPath()));
usuarioRegistro.setImagen(dir.getCanonicalFile());
```

And the exception is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1591)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1520)
at com.ucab.javachat.Servidor.model.ServidorModel.run(ServidorModel.java:198)
```

The line ServiorModel.java:198 is: ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(dir.getCanonicalPath()));

In my tests i can send images of 20, 30, 80, 200 Kb, but when i try to send the 2.1mb file gives the error.

I think this i related with some data loose on the byteArray (maybe header data?) but what i dont know is how to fix it, my register window method uses the same sockets and OutputStream to send data and i succesfully send a 24mb image.

Comment: `usuario.getImagen().getCanonicalPath())` What is the value that is returned here?

Comment: Well, the image is null, as the error message indicates. It's null because ImageIO.read() returned null. And ImageIO.read() returned null because of the reason indicated in the javadoc: no reader was able to read the image. Your image file is probably invalid, or of a format that is not supported by Java.

Comment: @GeorgeD in the client returns the local path of the file (the path on my computer)

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied File with
>   an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those currently
>   registered. The File is wrapped in an ImageInputStream. **If no
>   registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream,
>   null is returned**. The current cache settings from getUseCacheand
>   getCacheDirectory will be used to control caching in the
>   ImageInputStream that is created.
>
> Note that there is no read method that takes a filename as a String;
>   use this method instead after creating a File from the filename.
>
> This method does not attempt to locate ImageReaders that can read
>   directly from a File; that may be accomplished using IIORegistry and
>   ImageReaderSpi.

Make sure you register an ImageReader or wrap your file on a FileInputStream, but since your implementation works I bet it's the image causing issues therefore,

Make sure that your image is of type: GIF, PNG, JPEG, BMP, and WBMP for these are the types supported by the class.

Comment: Is a JPG image, and if i use the same image to register works perfectly, the problem comes only in modification

Comment: Is there a chance that the image might be corrupted? Do you create the images via the same method? The original and the modified one

Comment: its not the same method but is the same code, exact same instructions, the image is a image downloaded from internet, i think it cant be corrupted because work with register well